# php get week elapsed

Tags: php, date

How to get elapsed week with start and end date, and week is started with Monday to Sunday

Example:

```
start - end = output week
2013-11-20 - 2013-11-24 = 1 week
2013-11-20 - 2013-11-28 = 2 weeks
2013-11-20 - 2013-12-10 = 4 weeks
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNIX like time to easily manipulate things. Assuming `$start` and `$end` are in `format YYYY-MM-DD`

```
$start = strtotime($start);                //To convert it into UNIX time
$end = strtotime($end);
echo "Number of weeks are : ".(($end-$start)/7*24*60*60);
```

This will print the number of weeks.